# Tooltip in UIWebView with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, tooltip

I would like to create basic word translation in webView when user tap on specific word (on screenshot below blue font color). Contents of webView come from server as html and the word which should be translate looks like this:

```
<a href title="czasopismo">newspaper</a>
```

[image]

In my method shouldStartLoadWithRequest from webView delegate I can catch when user tap on this word, but I don't know how to get value title from < a > tag. The second problem is how to get position (CGPoint) where user tap on word and show tooltip there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scheme to get the value of `<a>`, so:

```
scheme://<a_value>
```

and in your callback you check the `request.URL.scheme`.

For the position you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to UIWebView and in the action of the gesture you have the point of tap.

**EDIT:**

You can write `<a title="czasopismo" onClick="onLinkClicked(this)">`

then with js:

```
<script>
  function onLinkClicked(sender) {
    window.location.href = 'tooltip://' + sender.title;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I pasted request.URL!.scheme in shouldStartLoadWithRequest method, but it return only "applewebdata" when I tap on < a >.

Comment: @DanielQ Try with `request.URL!.resourceSpecifier`

Comment: resourceSpecifier return this: "//1150B022-15C6-4DFF-B0E5-3462A2005C0C"

Comment: @DanielQ Ok, this means that your scheme is `applewebdata://1150B022-15C6-4DFF-B0E5-3462A2005C0C`, therefore your tag is `<a href="applewebdata://1150B022-15C6-4DFF-B0E5-3462A2005C0C" >`, isn't it? if you want your title you should write `<a href="tooltip//czasopismo">`

Comment: Ok, so if I use <a href=\"czasopismo\">newspaper</a> resourceSpecifier return "//7B45ADFB-91DE-43DD-B5A1-53D81892256D/czasopismo" so it's working properly. But I would like to know, is it possible to get title value from <a >? Server return tooltip in title not in href so it's problematic..

Comment: @DanielQ I updated my answer with an example of what you could do, let me know it is possible in your situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120638/discussion-between-saintthread-and-danielq).